# What is the difference between TwilioRestClient and Twilio.Device, why I can call using RestClient but can't have live voice?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I try to call my phone number by Twilio. I manage to do that by call action method:

```
public ActionResult Call(string toNumber) {
    client = new TwilioRestClient(Settings.AccountSid, Settings.AuthToken);        
    var result = client.InitiateOutboundCall(Settings.TwilioNumber, toNumber, "http://twimlets.com/message?Message%5B0%5D=http://demo.kevinwhinnery.com/audio/zelda.mp3");     
    if (result.RestException != null) {
        return new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult(500, result.RestException.Message);
    }    
    return Content("Call enroute!");
}
```

When I answer the phone the mp3 specified in the url is played. I want live 2-way audio.
In some examples from Twilio like : https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/client/outgoing-calls I see usage of capability token:

```
var capability = new TwilioCapability(accountSid, authToken);
    capability.AllowClientOutgoing(appSid);
    capability.AllowClientIncoming("jenny");
    string token = capability.GenerateToken();
```

and Twilio Device: `Twilio.Device.setup('@token');`.

Why am I even able to make phone call without generating capability token in my example? Can I somehow create `Twilio.Device` in C# not javascript? Should I pass capability token as model from controller?

Answer (score 2):

The Twilio.Device namespace is exclusive to the Twilio Client libraries (For iOS, Android, or the JS library for a web browser). If you think of your smart phone or your web browser as a possible device for voice communications, it'll be a little bit easier to do what you want to do. If you want to be able to communicate with your phone on the computer, you will have to generate the capability token in .Net, and then setup your device in the browser so that you can talk through your computer.

Read more here about capability tokens:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/capability-tokens

Comment: I am very sorry, but I got confused, I would like to use Chrome on my notebook to call normal phones(cell phones, standard phones). As I understood I need:
1.Generate capability token on the server side(controller)
2. Pass it to the client side(to the browser)
3. Use Twilio Client. \n
Please correct me I got confused at: "of your smart phone or your web browser" and then "setup your device in the browser".
Thank you for help.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You are exactly correct in your understanding. The reason that you can make an outbound call that then asks for your twimlet from your action result is that you don't need to setup a device to do that. All you are doing is sending instructions to Twilio. To actually use chrome on your notebook, you will need to do what you described above and initate a twilio device using a generated capability token.